# Creating very high resolution map image with appropriate scale

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am building a map to use as a texture on a 3D globe (for North America). The PNG will be about 16,000 pixels wide, and labels should be sized such that they look appropriate when about 2 US states or so wide of the image is viewable on screen for my application. It must use an equirectangular (plate carree) projection.

Because OSM data and the various styles are downloaded as rendered tiles, I have not been able to figure out a way using QGIS to get the scale correct in the print layout. So, I downloaded a PBF file of all North American OSM data and made a SpatiaLite database, connected that to QGIS, and am filtering for highway=motorway to only show major roads, and only show lines. I am creating labels, but this process is very time intensive and I'm not sure this is the best way to do this. So far the results have been mediocre, and I don't have things like state boundaries. Loading all of the data is too big, doing it state by state seems like it would take forever.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Have you considered using the Natural Earth data instead?

Comment: Using pre-rendered tiles will be a lot easier than creating your own map. I don't know what you mean when you say "I have not been able to figure out a way using QGIS to get the scale correct in the print layout"